# I want to add query string variables to JSON Name/Value Pairs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, keyvaluepair

I have a .asp page with a url of `page.asp?id=33&album=ourcookout`
page.asp calls a file.js
In the file.js there is a line under a function `url: "post_file.php",`
How can I get my id=33 and album=cookout on the end of the JSON Name/Value Pairs.

The end result I am looking for is url: `post_file.php?id=33&album=cookout`, but this could change to any id number and any album name.

How does the .js file dynamically add the variables to this key?

Answer (score 0):

in your asp file, add hidden fields;

```
<input type="hidden" id='myID' value="<%= Request("id") %>" />
<input type="hidden" id='myAlbum' value="<%= Request("album") %>" />
```

Make sure these are output on your page before the javascript is run.

Now, add the following to your javascript file, just before the JSON is prepared;

```
var myID = document.getElementById("myID").value;
var myAlbum = document.getElementById("myAlbum").value;
```

and then change the JSON preparation to;

```
url: "post_file.php?id=" + myID + "&album=" + myAlbum
```